# Are there any services that group multiple transactions together?

Tags: transactions, payment-batching

I discovered an interesting block that contains 10 inputs and nearly 200 outputs. Does this indicate the operation of a specific service, or is it simply a case of someone executing a large-scale distribution?

https://www.blockchain.com/ru/explorer/transactions/btc/8ecdbb5f430892606e00af76c9357389df0b3cd0bef72a45ad4c6ab7b93e170c

Answer (score 2):

As an example, exchanges and other custodial account providers typically batch together large numbers of transactions where their account holders are transferring money to recipients who are not account holders at the exchange.

Inferring specific organisations and processes is inexact and requires significant and extensive analysis work.